# Group by taxonomy term, show node multiple times for every reference

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a Content-Type called `client` and a Taxonomy term called `Service`. Inside the view I am showing content of type: node and grouping the nodes by the taxonomy reference field. Right now it is shown like this.

```
**Term Name1**
 node1
 node2

**Term Name2**
 node3
 node4
```

The problem is the term reference field is allowing multiple and I want to show the node referenced by more than one Term, under each term instead of views creating a new term grouping.

So say I reference node3 with `Term Name2` as well as `Term Name1` I get the following results:

```
**Term Name1**
 node1
 node2

**Term Name2**
 node4

**Term Name1, Term Name2**
 node3
```

How can I avoid this functionality and have the view show this instead?

```
**Term Name1**
 node1
 node2
 node3

**Term Name2**
 node3
 node4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the taxonomy term's settings, you need to uncheck the option for displaying the values in the same row.

[image: multiple_disable]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new view of content, show fields.

Under Advaced, relationship, add `taxonomy terms on node` and checkmark your tax term name and checkmark `require relationship`

In fields add field of `Taxonomy term: name` and checkmark `hide from display`

Next to Unformatted List click on `Settings` for **Grouping field Nr.1** select `(term) taxonomy term name`

[image]

Comment: OP's question is about the "multiple values" option in the field's settings. Building a view like this will default to showing multiple values on the same row. I added an answer for it.

Comment: @NiallMurphy the real question is `I want to show the node referenced by more than one Term, under each term instead of views creating a new term grouping.` this solution worked fine for me and displayed them how the OPer asked.

Comment: @NiallMurphy perhaps, your solution may solve the OPer's issue. It's hard to know not knowing how the view is set up. In my answer there is no need to do what you suggest to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I just tested yours and it works as well. It's slightly limited in that it seems to need the "Require this relationship" checked to work meaning nodes with no term won't be in the view. Good to know though.